# POM for org.springframework:springloaded:jar:1.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT is missing

Tags: spring, maven, maven-2, yeoman-generator, jhipster

I followed the directions listed on the jHipster website under
http://jhipster.github.io/creating_an_app.html

```
yo jhipster

mvn spring-boot:run

Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/mojo/maven-metadata.xml
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-metadata.xml
Downloaded: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-metadata.xml (13 KB at 53.3 KB/sec)
Downloaded: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/mojo/maven-metadata.xml (22 KB at 93.3 KB/sec)
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.382 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2014-05-03T21:45:53-05:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 8M/81M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] No plugin found for prefix 'spring-boot' in the current project and in the plugin groups [org.apache.maven.plugins, org.codehaus.mojo] available from the repositories [local (/Users/jgs/.m2/repository), central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/NoPluginFoundForPrefixException
```

This is the reference for springloaded in the pom.xml

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <argLine>-XX:MaxPermSize=128m -Xmx256m</argLine>
                <forkCount>1</forkCount>
                <reuseForks>false</reuseForks>
                <!-- Force alphabetical order to have a reproducible build -->
                <runOrder>alphabetical</runOrder>
                <classpathDependencyExcludes>
                    <classpathDependencyExclude>org.springsource.loaded:springloaded</classpathDependencyExclude>
                </classpathDependencyExcludes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there is a bug in the current yeoman generator. I was able to resolve this by using the plugin in the [jhipster sample project](https://github.com/jhipster/jhipster-sample-app/blob/master/pom.xml).

```
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <arguments>
                            <argument>--spring.profiles.active=prod</argument>
                        </arguments>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have simply doubts that you will use SNAPSHOT as you required by using in your example.

```
org.springframework:springloaded:jar:1.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT
```

You should use this:

```
org.springframework:springloaded:jar:1.2.0.RELEASE
```

instead. So you need to change the version entries in your pom file accordingly.

Comment: I don't see a listing of the reference JAR in the project pom.xml the yeoman generator produces the POM based on this template https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/blob/master/app/templates/_pom.xml

Comment: Is there a way to change the dependency version to RELEASE in the pom?  This dependency is coming from a resource in jhipster.

Answer (score 0):

You must just choose you folder project:

Go to `run` → `debug configuration` → `build maven` → `browser workspace`.

Finally choose your project folder.

Answer (score 0):

The same message is also displayed when you chose to use **gradle** during the jhipster setup phase (kinda obvious). Maven is not complaining about the missing pom.xml but generates this obscure message.

For gradle based builds the command is

```
gradlew bootRun
```

then get some coffe cause its gonna download loads! of stuff